# Parse read messages in Python

Tags: python, email, gmail

I have read several answers about how to read the email in Python. All of them partially work, as it does not handle correctly read messages or messages restored from the trash. My question is therefore: how can I read messages that are marked as read? Is there a more robust way to do this in Python? Here is the code I am using:

```
import poplib
import email

mailServer = 'pop.gmail.com'
emailID = 'myemail'
emailPass = 'mypass'

myEmailConnection = poplib.POP3_SSL(mailServer)
myEmailConnection.user(emailID)
myEmailConnection.pass_(emailPass)
EmailInformation = myEmailConnection.stat()

numberOfMails = EmailInformation[0]
for i in range(numberOfMails):
    print(myEmailConnection.retr(i+1)[1])
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible with the POP3 protocol. If you look at the [comparison with IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol#Comparison_with_IMAP) on Wikipedia, it mentions one of the advantages of IMAP is that it supports "message state: for example, whether or not the message has been read", while POP3 generally just retrieves new messages and downloads them (sometimes deleting them form the server).